# Contact Form - reply spammed

Tags: html, asp.net, macos, email, dns

My ex- colleague wrote a basic aspx contact form for one of our hotel clients before leaving, all has been fine with it (as far as i know)until a hosting issue this week.  It basically just sends form details onto the hotels email address.

When sending a test mail this week I noticed that although the email was received without any issues st the hotel end - their reply to my email address was marked as spam via my macs mail filter.

I should point out that the email address i used to test the form was a yahoo address which is added to my imacs mail account, when checking yahoo itself it wasn't in the spam folder and was displayed in the inbox as suspected. - it was only highlighted as spam (yellow color)on the imac.  So hopefully I'm worrying about very little!

This is a last min worry prior to going on holiday! - basically I don't understand much about mailouts - (I'm a designer who wishes he's never taken this job on!)  i just wanted to confirm whether the spam issue is anything to worry about and if so whether its a problem at the hotels end or with the form?

I'm hoping that the forms done its job by getting the mail to them so either just a fussy iMac which has a problem with their reply address or something else not related to the contact form itself..  If this is the case is there any advice i can offer them of anything they can add to the reply to stop it being spammed?

If anyone could offer any quick advice to save my piece of mind prior to going away - I'd be very greatful!

Thanks

Update: following the comments below - to clarify - the contact form sends a email to the hotel with the customers question and comments - this is received without issue.
The issue appears to be when the hotel reply to the enquiry their reply spammed for me (mac only).  The mx records for the email point to the previous domain and the site is hosted with us - the previous designer has control panel access for the DNs settings.

Comment: Is [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) configured correctly? in simple terms, is any mail sent by the server from a domain name that matches the IP? Many anti-spam filters try to ensure that stated sender isn't forged. See also [Forward-confirmed reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS). Based on what you said, this may be outside of your skillset, but it's at least a question you can ask to a network admin or hosting company.

Comment: Hi tim, we don't host the email for them, this is on a separate server.  Our script just sends an email to their email address, as I think their previous form did also.

Comment: The site itself was moved from the previous server but the email remained... Does that mean that all their email output could have a similar issue?

Comment: From what I understand the mx records still point to the previous host as they didn't want to disrupt their email accounts, but the site itself is now on a different domain..  Would thus cause the issue you mention?  If so will it always have been this way (all emails they now send)?  Which makes matters much worse I guess!

Comment: You can use any outgoing email address that you want when you send email programmatically. However, many spam filters will attempt to validate that it is truly from the stated domain. So I could send an email from your email address, but it would fail validation. It's possible that this is your problem, but definitely check with someone "in the know" before changing MX settings. If you have access to your specific settings, you could ask on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com). I'm not a DNS expert :)

Comment: Thanks tim, just to clarify - the email that is sent from the contact form on the website to the hotel is received fine at the hotels end.  They reply using their in house mail to the reply address provided on the form and its this reply that got spammed by my mac.  It's fine in yahoo/ gmail though.  So as the email reply is sent inhouse and not programmatically - does this mean they need to contact their mail host and ask them to look at the DNS settings do you think?  Thanks again for the advice by the way!

Comment: No problem. Based on that clarification, it's most likely an isolated incident or someone would have noticed a problem before now (and it's pretty standard practice to configure forward/reverse lookups for a corporate domain). It doesn't hurt to have them check their DNS, but it's more likely that something in the email content triggered an overly-sensitive spam filter.

Comment: Cool - so just to clarify - this means from a site / contact firm point of view all is cool as the hotel receives the mail ok and if a problem at all it would be with all their outgoing mail - which as you say would have been noticed by now?  If so I will inform them and ask them to get the previous host to check the dns settings...  Thanks very much for putting my mind more at rest- it's a nightmare trying to fix something you know nothing about!

Comment: You may get a quicker answer if you post your question here instead: http://serverfault.com/ and/or http://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the only thing that would be lost is the confirmation email (at worst), not the actual contact info that was submitted from the site. All the better if someone familiar with the environment can take a look at DNS.

Comment: Cheers tim!  Much appreciated